# Running Total in SQL Server recursion

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
CREATE TABLE #tblTasks
    (
    TaskID int,
    BasedOn int,
    Interval int
    )

INSERT INTO #tblTasks
    (TaskID, BasedOn, Interval)
SELECT 1, 2, 5 UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 3, 3 UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 4, 2

;WITH rCTE(TaskID, BasedOn, Interval, TaskLevel) AS
(
SELECT TaskID, BasedOn, Interval, 1 AS TaskLevel
FROM #tblTasks
WHERE TaskID = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT e.TaskID, e.BasedOn, e.Interval, TaskLevel + 1
FROM #tblTasks e
INNER JOIN rCTE c ON e.TaskID = c.BasedOn
)

SELECT * FROM rCTE

DROP Table #tblTasks
```

The code above produces this output:

```
TaskID----BasedOn----Interval----TaskLevel

1----2----5----1

2----3----3----2

3----4----2----3
```

I need a running total of the interval column. So I need a 5th column which, using the example above would show

```
TaskID----BasedOn---Interval----TaskLevel----TotalInterval

1----2----5----1----5

2----3----3----2----8

3----4----2----3----10
```

How can I create the `TotalInterval` column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add just a little bit of code

```
CREATE TABLE #tblTasks
    (
    TaskID int,
    BasedOn int,
    Interval int
    )

INSERT INTO #tblTasks
    (TaskID, BasedOn, Interval)
SELECT 1, 2, 5 UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 3, 3 UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 4, 2

;WITH rCTE(TaskID, BasedOn, Interval, TaskLevel,IntervalTotal) AS
(
SELECT TaskID, BasedOn, Interval, 1 AS TaskLevel, Interval as IntervalTotal
FROM #tblTasks
WHERE TaskID = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT e.TaskID, e.BasedOn, e.Interval, TaskLevel + 1, c.IntervalTotal+e.Interval
FROM #tblTasks e
INNER JOIN rCTE c ON e.TaskID = c.BasedOn
)

SELECT * FROM rCTE

DROP Table #tblTasks
```

Comment: thank you for your help. I kept adding c.Interval + e.Interval and it was adding one row to the next.